# GroupBy Knockout.js

Tags: c#, razor, knockout.js, group-by

I have this Razor code in C# and try to do the same in Knockout

```
 @foreach (var group in Model.Details.SonstigeNummern.OeReferenznummern.GroupBy(x => x.Hersteller))
                {
                    <tr class="ListItem @oddeven">
                        <td>@group.Key</td>
                        <td>
                            @foreach (var nummer in group)
                            { 
                                @nummer.Nummer<br />
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

I have no clue how i could manage the GroupBy.

My Viewmodel has the same Syntax as my c# model

Can Someone help with this?

Sincerly

Comment: Please post the json data

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be nicer (and easier) to group data on the client. Knockout specifically is for view building, so you should avoid building the view on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the linq query. But I think you should do something like this.
As you can see I just convert all data into arrays and then into JSON string.
And on this client side I re-convert them into javascript Object.

```
<table data-bind="foreach: groups">
     <tr class="ListItem @oddeven" >
        <td data-bind="value: Key"></td>
        <td data-bind="foreach: Nummers">
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var data= JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Details.SonstigeNummern.OeReferenznummern.GroupBy(x => x.Hersteller).Select( g => new {Key = g.Key, Nummers =  g.ToArray()}).ToArray()))');
    var vm = { groups: data};
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

I hope it helps.